# Phonegap barcodescanner plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am developing an app with cordova and I wanted to use the following barcode scanner:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

I installed the plugin with:

```
phonegap plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

Now there exists a new subfolder in the plugins folder named com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.

Seems correct to that point.

But now when I run that application on my phone, I get a page with

```
cordova.require object should exist
BarcodeScanner plugin should exist

module cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found
```

my config.xml doesn't even have the following line yet:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner"/>
```

But even when I add this line, it does not change a thing.

What do I have to do, to load the plugin successfully?

Comment: Post some code of your app, maybe there are some clues

Comment: I can't post everything, since it's too much and I don't understand of what use that could be.

The app doesn't work anymore, when the subfolder in plugin is added, while the code remains unchanged. I don't think a non-used plugin should change the behaviour of an app, but it seems it does. Maybe there is a good reason for that and I just don't realize.

If you can tell me what part of the code could be interesting, I can post it here.

Thank you for replying.

Comment: are you calling the plugin (`cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(...);`) in your code?

Comment: Nope, no call, no import via script tag, no entry in confix.xml. Literally nothing, but it still breaks my app.

Answer (score 0):

Im have an app with this plugin and this is my code works.

When your deviceready is trigger then:

`var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");`

```
       `scanner.scan( function (result) { 
        window.open(result.text, '_system', 'location=yes');
        /*
        alert("We got a barcode\n" + 
        "Result: " + result.text + "\n" + 
        "Format: " + result.format + "\n" + 
        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);  */

       console.log("Scanner result: \n" +
            "text: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "cancelled: " + result.cancelled + "\n");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = result.text;
        console.log(result);
        /*
        if (args.format == "QR_CODE") {
            // Your code
        }
        */

    }, function (error) { 
        console.log("Scanning failed: ", error); 
    } );`
```